# How to make text depending on my image height

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've got this item inside a LazyColumn but I can't seem to be able to make the blue column have the same height than my icon. The second text is optional.
I have the following code

```kotlin
Row(
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red).padding(8.dp)
) {
    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Check,
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.3f).aspectRatio(11.5f / 16).background(Color.Green)
    )
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .background(Color.Blue)
    ) {
        Text(item.name)
        Text(
            text = "This is a loooooooooooooooo oooooooo oooooooooooooooo ooooooo ooooooooooo oooooooooooooo oooooooo ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong description!!",
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        )
    }
}
```

I have tried putting `Modifier.fillMaxHeight()` on my `Column` and `height(IntrinsicSize.Min)` but it didn't work :/

[image: Preview]

Any help is appreciated :)